# Should I use “philosophy” as a noun to describe my world view?

Tags: philosophy

I do this often. I use the word "philosophy" to indicate I am talking about the way I think. I use it to indicate my own personal beliefs and conclusions about the world. It is in a sense a disclaimer at times as, "In my philosophy...", or, "My philosophy is...". In a way I am warning people to take what I am about to say as "something to think about", rather than fact. It might be true and I think it is. I can't prove it to you, maybe it can't be proven, there is evidence though. Another phrase I like to use is, "Philosophically speaking...". Does anyone else do this sort of thing? Is there a better way to start such a statement, in particular with someone who does not study philosophy? What tags should I include for this question?

Comment: Depends on if you're really talking about something philosophical or not. For instance, "In my philosophy Coca-cola tastes good" should rather be "In my opinion..." since there's no way to justify it being a philosophical thought.

Comment: That is one use of the word *philosophy*, yes.

Comment: This seems more like a request for open-ended "forum-style" discussion and would be welcome at [chat]. A Stack Exchange main site is not a forum. Actually we're looking for questions that our expert volunteers can give a definite "correct" answer to. For more information about asking, please see our "[On Topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" help page.

Comment: Well I posted this on the philosophy exchange and they seemed to think it should be posted here. I disagreed. I felt it was on topic for semantics. Others felt it was a question for etymology.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Shakespeare would agree with you.

> There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, 
>   Than are dreamt of in your philosophy. 
>   - Hamlet (1.5.167-8), Hamlet to Horatio

Comment: I can see some similarities between myself and Horatio...

Comment: Hamlet is Shakespeare's answer to critics who ask, "Why are your tragic heroes so dumb?"

Comment: I don't think Shakespeare is doing the same thing as what the original poster wrote about. In Shakespeare's day, if I'm not mistaken, "philosophy" included what we would now consider the sciences and all subjects whose mastery requires book-learning.

Comment: Philosophy as a system of knowledge rather than an attitude towards the universe; yes.  I am a scientist so perhaps the two have more in common for me than for most....

Comment: Does philosophy include science up to a point...or line, after which it is science? Or does philosophy encompass all pursuits of knowledge?

Comment: In Shakespeare's times, philosophy meant science.

Comment: Not necessarily. See the [paragraph](http://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/full/10.1086/673910) starting with "Usually when Shakespeare uses the word philosophy, he does so in the conventional stoic sense."